# How to run a multi-queue code using OpenCL?

Tags: queue, kernel, opencl

For example, I'm doing some image processing work on every frame of a video.

Every frame's processing using 200ms including writing, processing and reading.
And the fps is 25, in that case every two frames' distance is 40ms. Then the processing is too slow to show continuous result.

So here is my idea, I use multi-queues for this work.

In CPU part,

```
while(video is not over)
{
   1. read the frame0;
    processing the **frame0** using **queue0**;
    wait 40 ms;

   2. read the frame1;
    processing the frame1 using **queue1**;
    wait 40 ms;

    3.4.5. 
    ...(after 5 frames(just about the 200ms's processing time))


    6. download the **frame0**'s result.

    7. read the frame5;
    processing the frame5 using **queue0**;
    wait 40 ms;
    ...
}
```

The code means that, I use different queues for reading and processing the same frame in a video.

However, my experiment result is faster, but just 2 times faster, but not in my imaginary speed.

Can anyone tell me how to deal it? THX!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have one Device, here are some thoughts on this point:

- Main reason to have multiple Command Queues (CQ) per single OpenCL Device is the ability to execute kernels & do IO operations simultaneously.
- Usually one CQ is enought to load single Device at ~100%. Though, your multi-CQ idea is good (in my opinion), as you're constantly feeding GPU with workload.
- Look at kernel execution time. May be, it's big enough, so that your Device is constantly executing kernels & can't go any faster.
- I think, you don't need to wait for 40ms. Good solution is to process frames in queue, in which they are put to eliminate the difference between bitstream & display order.
- If you have too many CQ, your OpenCL driver thread will be busy maintaining them, so that performance may decrease.

Comment: Agreed. Having multiple command queues and cycling through them is *not* going to make it go faster. The better way to leverage multiple command queues is to use one for upload, one for compute, and one for download, and pipeline your work so you are downloading frame one while processing frame 2 while uploading frame 3. You need to use Events to synchronize it all. On single-DMA machines the upload and download will run sequentially but on dual-DMA machines they will overlap. However, if your kernel still isn't fast enough you're going to have to optimize it. Profile, improve.